# jQuery grid layout with resizable panels

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to do a simple layout for my html page, and I need some kind of grid layout.

The layout should be like the one in the image:

[image]

with the ability to make one of the widget full screen, so that it takes the whole widgets' area as you can see in the following image:

[image]

Finally, the content of each widget should be resized dinamically to fit the widget itself (I'm using full svg contents, so it should be enough to use `transform=scale(w,h)`)

Another needed feature is the animation of the resizing.

Now, since I'm quite new to html+javascript world, I've spent the whole day looking for some cool *jQuery* plugin to help me in this task and I've ended up with two useful plugins:

- [Freewall](http://vnjs.net/www/project/freewall/)
- [Gridster](http://gridster.net) (which I used to make the sample images)

The problem is that both of them are missing something that I need: they don't allow me to move the blocks within code but they only work with mouse interactions.

This means that I can't expand `widget2` to take the full area because it will expand starting from the current position and I can't move it.

Another problem is that I can't remove the widgets that I don't need to show.

With *Freewall* I can use filtering but, for example, filtering on *widget 1* makes the *widgets 2*'s row disappear and the *footer* is moved up.

With *Gridster* there's a `remove_widget` method and it works, but I'll need its html to add it back again.

So I built a custom solution based on *jQuery* and some kind of hand-written calculations to deal with `div`'s size and stuff like that, and it works fine but it's really a pain to use it because everytime I change something I'm forced to use `Firebug` to see which are the dimensions that I need, like a trial and error method.

It often happens that two divs of the same size require different `transform` options and it's really hard to work with that solution.

So the question is: **is there any plugin/framework that allows me to build a layout like the one in the images and with the features that I wrote?**

This could be summarized like a mosaic view, with one of the boxes wider than the others and the ability to make a box into full screen.

Comment: There are tons of grid systems out there, but I'm not certain if I understand what you are asking for when you say the resizing needs to be animated. When you say each widget should resize dynamically, do you mean the layout should change based on screen width or by clicking on a widget? Or by something else entirely?

Comment: Do you have any code so far?

Comment: My code is a complete mess and I need to start from something new. As for the animations, just watch the 2 images: in the first one there are 3 widgets, while in the second one there's only one of them. Making *widget 1* full screen means that the other 2 fade out while *widget 1*'s `height` is animated to fill the whole space

Comment: It's not the goal of a grid system to make them animated by default. Rather the purpose of a grid system is to make the grid as extensible and lightweight as possible. You could try using a grid system like Bootstrap or Zurb Foundation and also use some jQuery to animate those components.

Comment: After quick inspection of Freewall, it looks like it can do exactly what you want. In fact, Gridster can do what you want as well. Web applications don't just make themselves. You have to program the interaction.

Comment: Both of them require me to animate the squares and move them by setting their `css` properties like `top` or `left`, there's no way to programmatically move them into fixed layout positions. If I'm forced to manually change those properties, I can keep on using my custom solution.